# Does 'dust yourself off/down' (AmE/BrE) have the same literal and figurative meanings?

Tags: british-english

Taking the figurative sense, a common AmE saying:

> Pick yourself up, dust yourself off, and start all over again.

No one is necessarily physically down or dusty. Someone could have just fallen off a horse or they could've had a bad dating experience some time ago. Without context, we don't know (in AmE).

But what are the possibilities in BrE?

1. Would one say 'Dust yourself down' (in a literal sense) if someone was just dusty?

> What on earth happened to your suit? [Earth happened.] Dust yourself
> down.

2. Or is that used only for the figurative sense (or, perhaps, a combination of both)?

For example, the character Eudoria (played by Helena Bonham Carter) on *Enola Holmes 2* says this to her daughter Enola (1:19:42, after the carriage wreck and fight scene):

> So, you dust yourself down…keep facing forward.

The [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dust%20oneself%20down) entry only addresses the literal sense and not *yourself* specifically:

> **dust oneself down** idiom
>
> British
> : to brush the dirt/dust off one's clothes
> He stood up and *dusted himself down.*

I couldn't find the "idiom" in Cambridge, Collins, or any idiom dictionary online.
I wonder now if it's current BrE or what.

Edit:
Maybe I overcomplicated it. I'll rephase it for clarity.

**Question:**

> If I said 'Go outside and dust yourself down' (vs. dust yourself off)
> because your clothes were very dusty, would that be idiomatic in BrE?

I'll just assume the figurative use in the dialogue is, or was, idiomatic (and possibly dramatic) because it's a British film, almost entirely.

Answer (score 1):

*Oneself* in the definition implies that *myself, yourself, himself* etc. can all be substituted. See [this definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dust-off#:%7E:text=2.-,phrasal%20verb,which%20has%20affected%20their%20life.).

It says that 'dust *down*' is a British usage. (If you are brushing dust off your clothes you normally do it from the top down!)

[This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dust+yourself+down&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) indicates that a good many of the recent examples are figurative.

Comment: I believe OP wants to know whether *dust down* is used figuratively by Brits. Or are they just particularly dirty?

Comment: Sure, but you can also *dust off* your clothing.

Comment: The implication is that they all can be substituted, but are they actually? IDK at all, and I don't think MW really does either… 'Go outside and *dust yourself down* before you soil my new furniture.' If I had found example sentences like that, I would've assumed it was idiomatic in BrE. But I didn't…so I guess it's not?? IDK. Thanks for the linked definition.

Comment: In any case, TSM, +1.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs These things are transferable. One doesn't need to write it out for each one. Of course, he went outside and dusted himself down. I went outside and dusted myself down. etc, etc, for the other persons. I mean...

Comment: @Lambie - I wasn't interested in any -*self* form except *yourself* in a fixed command (see title). And I was primarily asking about the literal sense (see #1 and rephrase under **Question**) and for confirmation on the figurative sense (see #2) b/c it is used in a movie, a "British period piece" made by Brits for American girls and residual fans of Stranger Things, quite frankly; we still love Eleven, not Sherlock so much. I realize now it's Americanized BrE, by and large; and I'll take it w/grain of salt, along with my -1 which seems valid now but rather dismissive in @ holey way (AmBrE).

Comment: To spell it out more simply, then - _Dust yourself down_ can be used in British English both literally and figuratively.

Answer (score 1):

The usual idiom is pick yourself up and dust yourself off in AmE and BrE but just dust (yourself) off can be used also.
Also, **dust yourself down** is British according to MW.
Also, dust off is used in both.

**

> Life is like a hurdle race. If you fall, pick yourself up, dust
> yourself off and take the next one at a run

**

[pick yourself up and dust yourself off: Dyslexia Scotland](https://dyslexiascotland.org.uk/life-is-like-a-hurdle-race-if-you-fall-pick-yourself-up-dust-yourself-off-and-take-the-next-one-at-a-run-2/)

> Didn’t get the job this time? Dust yourself off and try again!

[gluerecruit in the UK](https://www.glurecruit.co.uk/6060-2/)

The expressions are also used in AmE.

Comment: I think MW's entry is an oversimplified catchall; IDK. Thanks for the UK links.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs Why would you need more than: Chiefly British??

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I rephrased my question, narrowed it (see **Question** at bottom). I'm tempted to delete all the rest, but I'm over it. I could ask my spouse, but he hasn't lived there in 60 years. What does he know—lorry, loo… It's a mystery! Haha, I'm good now. TSM, +1.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs That is what the MW dictionary says. Why do we need more than that? One expression is chiefly British, the other, as I point out is used on both sides of the pond. And dust himself down would also allow dust yourself down.

Comment: Where is the saying 'dust yourself down' (exactly) except in that dialogue? Have I missed it somewhere?

Comment: @HippoSawrUs Kate Bunting has covered that.

Comment: No worries. It hasn't been found verbatim in the literal sense, so I guess that's far from common or idiomatic. I'm fine with that. I won't tell anyone to 'dust yourself down' unless it's a highly capable dog covered in fleas or something. Therein lies the difference…here. Didn't want to lead with that…oh well.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs I know of few expressions like this that cannot be used figuratively. But as Kate Bunting has pointed out: it is British